# Unable to display mapped property on display template

Tags: search-results, display-template, people-search

I have mapped "otherTelephone" to the "Extension" field in my managed property mapping, but I am unable to now display this on a custom display template.

In the display template, I have the following mapped properties

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'AboutMe':'AboutMe','AccountName':'AccountName', ..... 'otherTelephone':'Extension'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

I am then calling the this in the template like so

```
<!--#_ 
                if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
                    var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
                    var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
                    var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
                    $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
                    var container_id = id + "_peopleContainer";
                    var hhProps = Srch.U.createXMLDocument("<root>" + ctx.CurrentItem.HitHighlightedProperties + "</root>");
                    var encodedPath = $urlHtmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path);
                    var has_pn = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.PreferredName);
                    var has_sip = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.SipAddress);
                    var has_email = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.WorkEmail);
                    var has_jt = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.JobTitle);
                    var has_dp = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Department);
                    var has_abme = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.AboutMe);
                    var has_resp = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Responsibilities);
                    var has_pp = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.PastProjects);
                    var has_ski = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Skills);
                    var has_sch = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Schools);
                    var has_int = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Interests);
                    var has_vlm = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.ProfileViewsLastMonth);
                    var has_vlw = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.ProfileViewsLastWeek);
                    var has_query = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.ProfileQueriesFoundYou);
                    var has_extn = !$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.Extension);
                    var isSelfSrch = (has_vlm == true || has_vlw == true || has_query == true);
                    var delimiter = "";
                    var userPersonaId = $htmlEncode(id) + "_peopleUserPersona";
                    var uSip = ctx.CurrentItem.SipAddress;
                    var uEmail = ctx.CurrentItem.WorkEmail;
                    var uName = ctx.CurrentItem.PreferredName;
                    var uPicUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.PictureURL;
                    var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Person_HoverPanel.js";

                    var encodedName = (has_pn == true) ? $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.PreferredName) : $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.YomiDisplayName);
                    var displayName = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "preferredname");
                    if ($isEmptyString(displayName)) { displayName = encodedName }

                    if(has_jt == true) {
                      var encodedJtitle = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.JobTitle);
                      var displayJtitle = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "jobtitle");
                      if ($isEmptyString(displayJtitle)) { displayJtitle = encodedJtitle }
                    }

                    if(has_dp == true) {
                      var encodedDept = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Department);
                      var displayDept = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "department");
                      if ($isEmptyString(displayDept)) { displayDept = encodedDept }
                    }


_#-->

                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-vb2"><a clicktype="Result" id="NameFieldLink" href="_#= encodedPath =#_" title="_#= encodedName =#_">_#= displayName =#_</a></td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2">_#= displayDept =#_</td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2">_#= displayJtitle =#_</td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2"><a href="mailto:_#=uEmail=#_">_#=uEmail=#_</a></td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.WorkPhone=#_</td>
                        <td class="ms-vb2">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Extension=#_</td>


                    </tr>
```

The display template is requesting `_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Extension=#_`

I can't seem to see why the value is not being passed through. On a normal profile page, I can see that the managed property is displaying the value.

Comment: Any chance you might be able to quickly peek into the properties of your 'CurrentItem' by placing a 'Console.Log(CurrentItem)' somewhere in this? You will quickly get to know whether you have an 'Extension' property or not.

Comment: Are you certain it is populated? Have you tried searching for it in the search center? Is it marked as Reurnable?

Comment: I finally worked out what was stopping it from appearing. I had to actually add a managed property, and map it to the "Extension" property that was being crawled. Added a managed property called "PhoneExtension", mapped to "People:Extension", updated the code and ta dah, it works.